# Shopping cart total price problems in Kentico

Tags: c#, kentico

I am using Kentico API to display my products on my website, but I'm facing a problem during displaying total shopping cart price. It rounds automatically - if the price is 11.5 it makes it 12.

Here is my method to return total price:

```
    public double GetTotalShoppingCart(int userID, string siteName)
    {
        double totalPrice=0.0;
        ShoppingCartInfo cartInfo = GetShopCard(userID, siteName);
        int siteID = GetSite(siteName);
        if (cartInfo != null)
        {
            DataSet cartItems = ShoppingCartItemInfoProvider.GetShoppingCartItems(cartInfo.ShoppingCartID);
            if (cartItems.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in cartItems.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    totalPrice += ShoppingCartItemInfoProvider.GetShoppingCartItemInfo(int.Parse(row["CartItemID"].ToString())).TotalPrice;   
                }
            }
        }
        return totalPrice;
    }
```

It returns the correct total price only if it's an integer or a real number but if it contains any fractions it rounds it to the highest number. Do you know what's causing the issue?

Comment: When you're debugging is `totalPrice` 11.5 or 12? If it's 11.5 then I wonder if you can modify the view so that it shows the correct number of decimal places maybe? Also, is there a reason you chose double instead of decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to use **decimal** but it also didn't work correctly so i calculated total price by my self some thing like:

```
public decimal GetTotalShoppingCart(int userID, string siteName)
{
    decimal totalPrice=0;
    ShoppingCartInfo cartInfo = GetShopCard(userID, siteName);
    int siteID = GetSite(siteName);

    if (cartInfo != null)
    {
        DataSet cartItems = ShoppingCartItemInfoProvider.GetShoppingCartItems(cartInfo.ShoppingCartID);
    if (cartItems.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in cartItems.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            totalPrice += decimal.Parse(row["SKUUnits"].ToString()) * decimal.Parse(row["SKUPrice"].ToString());//(decimal)ShoppingCartItemInfoProvider.GetShoppingCartItemInfo(int.Parse(row["CartItemID"].ToString())).TotalPrice;   
        }
    }
}
return totalPrice;

}
```

Thanks alot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

@Ksib raises a good point about using `decimal` stead `double`. Decimal will give you more precision. Also, express the price as numeric string and format as currency. See the remarks in the MSDN [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) and [double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) entries for a detailed explanation. MSDN's numeric formatting info is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If the following doesn't change how the data is viewed, then you'll have to change the view itself.

```
public decimal GetTotalShoppingCart(int userID, string siteName)
{
    decimal totalPrice = 0;
    ShoppingCartInfo cartInfo = GetShopCard(userID, siteName);
    // Not sure what siteID is used for here...
    int siteID = GetSite(siteName);
    if (cartInfo != null)
    {
        if (cartItems.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in cartItems.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                totalPrice += (decimal)ShoppingCartItemInfoProvider.GetShoppingCartItemInfo(int.Parse(row["CartItemID"].ToString())).TotalPrice;   
            }
        }
    }
    return totalPrice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the int.parse.  No matter what that is going to return a whole number.  Try using the Kentico ValidationHelper class and getting the double or decimal value, or you can use the same syntax you are using above with decimal.parse, etc.

Comment: `int.parse()` is being used for `GetShoppingCartItemInfo()`, not the actual math part.

Comment: Exactly...so its automatically giving you 12 to do your math with instead of 11.5.

Comment: You're not understanding what the `GetShoppingCartItemInfo()` does. It's like accessing an array. `int.Parse(row["CartItemID"].ToString())` is just taking the ID of the item and turning it into an `int` not the monetary value.